# finding the number of elements of $a_n=3n+4$ which divisible by $4$ without induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> Given the sequence $a_n=3n+4$, need to find the number of elements
>   which divisible by $4$ without reminder and without using induction.

I can see that $a_4=16$ is the first term which divisible by $4$, and $a_{124}=376$ is the last term.

so i guess i need the distance of $+12$ between each element for it to be valid (starting $b_1=16$ till $b_n=376$).

My problem is that it's all intuition.

How can i show all that in a mathematical writing?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: there are 126 elements in that sequence.

Comment: There is no last term - for any $n$ divisible by $4$ we have $a_n$ divisible by $4$.

Comment: What do you mean finding the number of elements? There are infinitely many of them. $ 4 \mid (3n + 4) \iff 4 \mid 3n \iff 4 \mid n \iff n \in \{4k, k \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: see my edit, i forgot to right this very crucial detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $3n+4$ is divisible by $4$ whenever $n$ is divisible by $4$. This can easily be seen by writing $n=4k$, so $a_n=3\cdot4k+4=4\cdot(3k+1)$. Since there are an infinite number of choices for $n$ of the form $4k$, there are clearly an infinite amount of values of $3k+4$ which are divisible by $4$.

EDIT: I think I understand your problem better now, it is just that you forgot to include the bounds to your sequence. It should be noted that if $3n+4$ is divisible by $4$, then $3n+4-4=3n$ is also divisible by $4$, and so $n$ must be divisible by $4$. Thus the entirety of the values in your sequence which are divisible by $4$ are those of the form $3\cdot 4k+4=12k+4$, and as you have guessed, the difference between two consecutive values of this form is $12$

EDIT 2: One way you can do this is to note that 1 out of every 4 numbers is divisible by four, so one way you can calculate how many numbers of the sequence are divisible by four is by finding $\lfloor{\frac{N}{4}}\rfloor$ where $N$ is the amount of numbers in the sequence. Since $N=126$, $\lfloor{\frac{N}{4}}\rfloor=\lfloor{31.5}\rfloor=31$

Comment: sorry, see my edit.

Comment: This shows that if $4\mid n$ then $4\mid a_n$. Missing is the reciprocal.

Comment: @Did the reciprocal is found in the edit

Comment: True. Why not rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: @Did I tend to make all of my edits clear so that OP is able to distinguish the old from the new. Not entirely useful in this case but it's more of a habit of mine

Comment: @ASKASK - but how can i get the answer $n=31$ in a formal way ? i can't understand that.

Comment: I added an update

Comment: @ASKASK  -thanks.and the other way is to build a new sequence such $b_1=16$, $b_n=376$ and $d=12$ so $376=16+12(n-1)$. right?

Comment: That would also work too